# Where does this DOM element get its styling from?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have this website where there is a green band displayed at the very top. 
Below an abstract from the html code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- start header -->
<header>
    <div class="site-top"> !this makes the green band at the top!
        <div class="container">
          <div>
            <div class="pull-right">
              <strong>
                <a href="http://localhost/dimi_test/admin">  ! this element is displayed as green text!
                 <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Dashboard
                </a>
              </strong>                                                                                              
            </div>
          ...
```

My problem is that the background of the `<div class="site-top">` is green and the font colour of the `<a>` element is the same green, making it invisible.
I tried to find out in which style sheet the `<a>` element is defined, so I opened google devtools. This is the result:

[screenshot Google devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrVhw.png)

It seems the element is defined in .(index):36, in the style sheets that are in the screenshot, the font colour is stricken through. So I do not understand where the DOM element `<a>` gets its styling from.

Hope my question is more clear now.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of what you are describing in the dev tools here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are describing is happening because there is [internal/embedded CSS](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/difference-between-inline-external-and-internal-css#Internal-CSS) within the HTML on that particular page in the `<head>` section.

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    1 ...
    2 ...
    ...
    36 a...{
         color: #72c02c;
       }
  </style>
</head>
```

You will need to remove or modify that to prevent it from overriding your external stylesheet (style.css).